# Unable to connect to MongoDB hosted in local

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

On a VPS with root rights, I can't connect to a local Mongo DB.

## mongo

=> this connection is OK
I created 2 users: one on `Admin db` et one on another `local db` where I have my collection.
With this user I can't connect to db:

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017 --ssl --username mongodb --password xxxxxxx --authenticationDatabase admin
```

```
2020-01-03T16:00:36.506+0100 W  CONTROL  [main] Option: ssl is deprecated.
```

Please use `tls` instead.
=> I tried with `tls` option but no use :

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2020-01-03T16:00:36.613+0100 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: short read :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

Any help is much appreciated.

And happy new year!
Theo

Answer (score 0):

Maybe mongodb service is not running. Start it and maybe try again.
Mongodb doc on how to start the service: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#run-mongodb-community-edition

Comment: Hello,  # ps -ef |grep mongo
mongod   14871     1  0 Jan03 ?        00:17:04 /usr/bin/mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf

Answer (score 0):

That error means the shell was **unable to talk to the server**. This is usually because the server *is not running or cannot be communicated with* (firewalls, etc). Since it's localhost I doubt it's a firewall issue, so it's probably the server not running.

The obvious statement (though sometimes worth mentioning) would be to **check if you've started the server**. Restart it to be sure (exact instructions will vary depending on server OS, which you haven't specified).

If that doesn't help then it's probably a case of the server not starting due to **configuration error**. MongoDB's log files would help debug this further. Common problems tend to be file permission issues, database corruption, etc. Since you mentioned SSL in your post it could be due to an invalid configuration of the server's SSL config.

We'd need log files to provide an answer that is more than just a guess. **Could you provide the logs for your MongoDB server?**

Comment: Hi thanks but if Mongodb is not running, how to explain i cann connect with only 'mongo' command so without user authentification et i canned create tow mongo users?

Comment: Hello Here is the end of  mongo log: # tail mongod.log
2020-01-03T16:02:15.822+0100 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:60010 #374 (1 connection now open)
2020-01-03T16:02:15.822+0100 I  NETWORK  [conn374] Error receiving request from client: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL handshake received but server is started without SSL support. Ending connection from 127.0.0.1:60010 (connection id: 374)
2020-01-03T16:02:15.822+0100 I  NETWORK  [conn374] end connection